# dealing with array of linked list

Tags: c, arrays, linked-list

**My approach:**

An array of fixed-length (lets say 20) each element is pointer to the first node of a linked list.
so i have 20 different linked list.

This is the structure:

```
struct node{
       char data[16];
       struct node *next;
};
```

My declaration for that array

```
struct node *nodesArr[20];
```

now to add a new node to one of the linked list, i do this:

```
struct node *temp;

temp = nodesArr[i]; // i is declared and its less than 20
addNode(temp,word); // word is declared (char *word) and has a value ("hello")
```

The addNode function:

```
void addNode(struct node *q, char *d){
    if(q == NULL)
        q = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    else{
        while(q->next != NULL)
            q = q->next;

        q->next = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        q = q->next;
    }

    q->data = d; // this must done using strncpy
    q->next = NULL; 
}
```

and to print data from the array of linked list, i do this:

```
void print(){
    int i;
    struct node *temp;

    for(i=0 ; i < 20; i++){
        temp = nodesArr[i];
        while(temp != NULL){
            printf("%s\n",temp->data);
            temp = temp->next;
        }
    }
}
```

now compiler gives no error, the program run and i pass the data to it, and when i call print it doesn't print any thing,,??

**UPDATE::**

after I edited the code (thx for you), i think the problem in the print function,, any idea ?

Comment: Have you tried stepping it through a debugger, or adding useful `printf` statements?

Comment: yeah i tried,, but i got nothing

Comment: You got nothing?  So you couldn't, for instance, discover at what point all the elements of `nodesArr` became `NULL`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem lies in `addNode()`. When the list is empty you do:

```
q = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
```

but the scope of `q` is limited to `addNode()`. You should have declared `addNode()` as

```
void addNode(struct node **q, char *d)
```

and adjust your code accordingly:

```
*q = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
```

and so on...

Comment: so that q = q->next , should be like this, *q = *q->next, or(*q)->next ??

Comment: If it makes it any easier, once you have allocated, you can assign the pointed-to address to a single pointer and keep the rest of the code more or less like you have it now. `struct node* sp;` and then later `sp = *q`

Comment: @Rami Jarrar: You have to use `*q = (*q)->next`. The C gurus will [tell you](http://www.difranco.net/cop2220/op-prec.htm) that `->` has a higher precedence than the dereference operator. The rest of us just use a pair of parentheses and don't bother thinking about it any more.

Comment: @Rami Jarrar: no, you need to use `addNode(&(nodesArr[i]), word);`. In your current version you are only modifying `temp` and not the place where it got its value.

Comment: thx,, but now I think the problem in the print function, did you see it ?

Answer (score 3):

When you pass `struct node *q` to `addNode` you are giving it an address for an element in your array. If you use `malloc` inside, then you are overwriting this variable `q`, which is local to the function and now points to something different, but you haven't changed your original array. Try using a pointer to pointer to node (`struct node **q`).

Answer (score 2):

```
void addNode(struct node *q, char *d){
    if(q == NULL)
        q = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
```

Here's the problem.

The new value of `q` doesn't ever get out of the function, so your array of linked lists never gets updated.

Normally the solution here is to use a double-pointer:

```
void addNode(struct node **q, char *d){
    if(*q == NULL)
        *q = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
```

And call it like so:

```
addNode(&nodesArr[i],word);
```

Then, if you `malloc` a new node, the value in the array will be set to point to the new node.

Answer (score -2):

```
struct node
{

  int actual, estimated;

  char c;

  struct node *next;

} *head[4], *var[4], *trav[4];


void
insert_at_end (char c, int value, int value1)
{

  struct node *temp;

  temp = head[i];

  var[i] = (struct node *) malloc (sizeof (struct node));

  var[i]->actual = value;

  //var1=(struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));

  var[i]->estimated = value1;

  var[i]->c = c;

  //printf("%d",var->estimated);

  if (head[i] == NULL)

    {

      head[i] = var[i];

      head[i]->next = NULL;

    }

  else

    {

      while (temp->next != NULL)

    {

      temp = temp->next;

    }

      var[i]->next = NULL;

      temp->next = var[i];

    }

}
```