# Printing an array of linked lists

Tags: c++, arrays, list

PLEASE HELP
I have this array list, each index having a different length linked list embedded. How do I print this?

```
#include <list>
#include <etc...>

for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
   std::cout << "Number of elements in row " << i << endl;
   std::cin >> s;
   s = s * 2;

   for (int j = 0; j < s; j++){
        std::cin >> k;
        listArray2[i].push_back(k);
   }

}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [dealing with array of linked list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4940043/dealing-with-array-of-linked-list)

Comment: Do you know how to print *one* list?